# Map some Fields of Dictionaries in a List

Tags: python, list, dictionary, collections

I have a list of dicts, what is the input. Some of the fields are HTML-encoded.

```
[
     {
       CONTENT:"<title>ABC</title>",
       bla: "Text",
       x: "<span>Test</span>"
     },
     { 
       CONTENT:"<b>def</b>",
       bla: "32",
       x:"<div><b>Test</b></div>"
     },
     ...
 ]
```

The list `fields` contains the fields to be transformed using an HTML-Stripper `_strip`:

```
fields = ["x", "CONTENT"]
```

What is the best way to map the value of these fields, in this case `CONTENT` and `x`, to `_strip(CONTENT)` respective `_strip(x)`.

My current code is looking like this, but I have some doubts because list and dicts are passed by reference and that this isn't the pythonic way to do this.

```
elements = map(lambda x: f(fields, x), elements)   

def f(fields, element):
    for field in fields:
        element[field] = _strip(element[field])
    return element
```

The expected result looks like this:

```
[
     {
       CONTENT:_strip("<title>ABC</title>"),
       bla: "Text",
       x: _strip("<span>Test</span>")
     },
     { 
       CONTENT:_strip("<b>def</b>"),
       bla: "32",
       x:_strip("<div><b>Test</b></div>")
     },
     ...
 ]
```

which is evaluated:

```
[
     {
       CONTENT:"ABC",
       bla: "Text",
       x: "Test"
     },
     { 
       CONTENT:"def",
       bla: "32",
       x:"Test"
     },
     ...
 ]
```

I don't ask for the `_strip`-function, but for a proper way to map this.

Comment: What's wrong with passing objects by reference into a function?

Comment: I do not think that it is generally wrong, but my guess is that in case of passing by reference the input is changed. Correct me if I am wrong. And I suppose that the map function is something that comes from functional programming.

Comment: Passing mutable objects into functions is perfectly fine, and it would be very difficult to do things of much use in Python without being able to do so. However, I think what you don't like is that you're editing an object and then returning the modified object, which I understand. A way of fixing this would be to create the modified element `mod_element = element.copy()`, and edit values there. I'll type up another answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method without editing `element` in place, using solely comprehensions:

```
[{k:(_strip(v) if k in fields else v) for k,v in element.items()} for element in content]
```

Note that this isn't Pythonic either as it's a one-liner, but you can split it up as you see fit.